# How to access date and varbinary from KDB+ in C api

Tags: c, kdb

Having trouble to get date and varbinary values in C program from KDB database. K (3.2t 2004-06-03)

```
types:  
date = `date  
col1 = `varbinary
```

query:

```
select date, col1 from table1 where date='1993-01-04'
```

result in K shell:

```
.((`date
,-15337
.,(`T;`date;))
(`col1
,"000  00010"
 ))
```

Result in C:

```
int date = KI(KK(kData)[0])[i];//date=-15337.
col1=KI(KK(kData)[1])[i];  //col1=8394164
```

Question: How do I convert -15337 to '1993-01-04'? It is before kdb epoch...
Question: How do I get actual varbinary "000 00010" from the result?

Thank you very much.

Comment: time values are unsigned, so -15337 is actually (in unsigned hex) FFFFC417h.  Amongst other things, this shows that the available dates for a 32bit time is going to end somewhere in 2036. (I'm expecting time values to go to 64bits before then.

Comment: what is the relationship between a data and the variable length binary value 00000010?

Comment: the string date can be gotten from the 0xFFFFC417 by using the localtime() function, followed by the strftime() function.

Comment: I have tried localtime and failed. As far as I know time32_t is seconds since epoch. I did little test to check output for query:
    1993-01-04=-15337
    1993-01-05=-15336
    1993-01-06=-15335
it looks like days not seconds.

Comment: relationship for varbinary? I pull it as integer and get those values that is obvious a mistake. I do not know how to pull varbibinary correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answers, Thank for responding user3629249

to access date use dj function

```
 cout << dj(KI(KK(kData)[0])[i]);
```

produces 19930104

access var binary as list.

```
K col1Data = KK(KK(kData)[6])[i];
int col1_size = col1Data->n;
for( int j=0; j<col1_size; j++ )
    cout << KC(col1Data)[j];
```

produces "000 00010"